Access MongoDB Atlas from Bitbucket Pipelines build environments
I am trying to do some CRUD MongoDB operations from bitbucket pipelines. I have a Dedicated MongoDB cluster hosted in MongoDB Atlas AWS Setup. The problem is I am not able to connect to the cluster from the Bitbucket pipelines build environment.
Currently, MongoDB Atlas provides 3 ways to allow network access

Whitelist IPs
Peering
Private Endpoint

I see Bitbucket provides a list of IPs to whitelist.
But maybe these IPs can change at any point and also it's a very long list to manage in Atlas.
Is there a better solution to allow bitbucket pipelines build environment to access Atlas clusters?
